# "check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON" when opening the terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, python, virtualenvwrapper

```
/home/isaac/anaconda3/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'virtualenvwrapper')
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks. 

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/home/isaac/anaconda3/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

How would I go about solving the above?

Comment: Did you set up the virtualenv(s) yourself?

Comment: Would not remember. Anyways, solved it. Just needed to run "pip3 install virtualenvwrapper".

Comment: OK, glad you got it sorted! Please post that as an answer (yes, you can answer your own question).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OP solved it.

Just needed to run the following:

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
```